# Cannot manage to change default gateway

Tags: default, gateway

As it is the first time I am asking a question, I do not know what to post to get an helpful answer.

Anyway, I cannot access internet through my network since this morning and tried everything but to no avail. The problem may come from my default route 192.168.1.201, which I did not manage to change back to 192.168.1.1 for device enp0s25. See:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.201   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s25
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx90f652059f8a
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx90f652059f8a
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx90f652059f8a
```

Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: Which device do you have set for your Internet access, your wired or wireless?  Have you manually setup a any configurations outside the default?  Can you add the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: This is the output of cat /etc/network/interfaces:   # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback - Is this what you need? Otherwise, I haven't set up anything manually and my computer is connected to the network via cable. There is also a wifi connection, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I solved the problem thanks to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1957680 by appending this to /etc/network/interfaces:
Code:

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp

Comment: You should have been able to do this via the: network icon in the top panel, edit connections, select `Wired Connection`, click the edit button, and set the dhcp and gateway info there. Cheers, Al